# Try to add async after script tag on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, asynchronous

I'm working on a wordpress theme I added a plugin name wp-fastest-cache which execute a script tag on head section

```
<script src='//mysite.com/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/fad3/13d93index.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I have tried lots of trick from stack overflow and google but failed.Lots of files I tried to edit like function.php, fucntion.wp-script.php etc. still stuck. I need to add async = 'async' like

```
<script async = 'async' src='//mysite.com/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/fad3/13d93index.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I know there are lots of plugins. But I want to do it manually.

And sorry for my bad english.

Thanks,

Comment: Not getting what are you asking, but try this `<script async defer  src='//mysite.com/wp-content/cache/wpfc-minified/fad3/13d93index.js' type='text/javascript'></script>` check [here](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html)  for more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following code inside functions.php to add `async` to the javascript.

```
if(!is_admin()){
    function defer_async_of_js ( $url ) {

        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return "$url' ";
        if ( strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) {
            return "$url' async='async' ";
        }
        else
        {
            return $url;
        }

    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_async_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_defer_attribute($tag, $handle) {

    // add script handles to the array below
    $scripts_to_defer = array('gform_recaptcha');
    foreach ($scripts_to_defer as $defer_script) {
        if ($defer_script === $handle) {
            return str_replace(' src', ' async src', $tag);
        }
    }
    return $tag;
}

add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_defer_attribute', 10, 2);

// Place above code in function file. you can add multiple id after comma. For Ex. ('gform_recaptcha', 'another_id');
```